# Linear combination of images in a cell

Tags: image, matlab

This seems like an obvious thing to do, but after a bit of research, I'm still stuck.

I have a cell of arrays of double (images) and I wish to add the respective elements of all the arrays of the cell. i.e. doing something like `imadd` would do, or `imlincomb`, without looping, and it should not depend on the number of images in the cell.

Unfortunately imlincomb needs the weights to be added and so something like `imlincomb(CellofArrays{:})` will not work.

Turning the cell into a matrix might be an option, but then I need to tailor the indices to retrieve the images. The images are of consistent size and type.

Any idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it pretty easily (unless I am missing something):

```
sum(cat(3,CellofArrays{:}),3)
```

This works by concatenating all arrays along the third dimension and then summing through that dimension.

Comment: It didn't like the cell in the sum. I found this to work better: `sum(cat(3,reshape(cell2mat(CellofArrays), [size(CellofArrays) numel(CellofArrays)],3)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly (if not, please provide a small code snippet with a few input values) you could proceed with the matrix to cell-conversion tactic as follows:

```
%input "images" of doubles stored as arrays in a cell
i{1} = [1 2 3 6; 4 5 6 2; 7 8 9 2];
i{2} = [2 3 4 6; 5 6 7 2; 9 1 4 5];
i{3} = [3 3 1 4; 4 1 5 1; 1 6 7 5];

%method
i_matrix_2d = cell2mat(i); % convert cells to a very wide matrix
ni = numel(i_matrix_2d); % count number of elements
si = size(i{1}); % determine pixel height and width per image
i_matrix_3d = reshape(i_matrix_2d,si(1),si(2),ni/si(1)/si(2)); % reformat matrix to three dimensions, where the third index is equal to the cell index of the input images
sum_of_pixels = sum(i_matrix_3d,3); % sum along third dimension
```

BR
Magnus

Comment: Yeah this is what I meant with tailoring the indices of the image after cell2mat conversion. I works, but it's clumsy.